# Error occurred in installing ThingsBoard Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am installing ThingsBoard on Raspberry Pi by following [this](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/rpi/) guide. It gave me an error when I tend run installation script in second last step:

### Run installation script:

`sudo /usr/share/thingsboard/bin/install/install.sh --loadDemo`

> Error creating bean with name `entityManagerFactory` defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested
> service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
>
> **ThingsBoard installation failed!**

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I am not sure if this question is better asked here, or on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Probably you haven't provided your JDBC path correctly.

Check your `thingsboard.yml` and add correct path inside `datasource:` block.